# Tuple constructor vs list comp

Tags: python, list, tuples

Just say I have a list

```
a = (3, 2, 9, 4)
```

And I want to add one to each number and store the result, (I won't need to manipulate the result after), my first thought would be to go:

```
[x + 1 for x in a]
```

But what about:

```
tuple(x + 1 for x in a)
```

Tuples are meant to be faster right? And if I don't need to change the result after is this code more efficient? Also how does it really work, does the `tuple` constructor have to create a list out of the generator expression to know the size in advance? Thanks in advance for any explanation.

Comment: The best thing to do is to actually time it.  The results could vary based on many factors, including which implementation of python you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just `timeit()`:

```
In : a = (3, 2, 9, 4)

In : f1 = lambda: [x + 1 for x in a]

In : f2 = lambda: tuple(x + 1 for x in a)

In : timeit.timeit(f1)
Out: 0.595026969909668

In : timeit.timeit(f2)
Out: 2.360887050628662
```

so it seems that the tuple constructor variant takes about four times as long, I guess because list comprehensions are fairly optimized (in cpython).

But let's take a closer look:

```
In : f3 = lambda: list(x + 1 for x in a)

In : timeit.timeit(f3)
Out: 2.5421998500823975
```

so this takes about the same time as the tuple construction, which indicates that the performance penalty lies in the generator expression overhead. (we can rule out list / tuple construction, see edit below)

It is even about twice as slow as to `map()` the list:

```
In : inc = partial(operator.add,1)

In : f4 = lambda:map(inc, a)

In : timeit.timeit(f4)
Out: 1.2346529960632324
```

I think this really boils down to (cpython) implementation details, so don't rely on this.
Anyway - don't worry about performance, it's just a factor of 2-4, use the method which is best to read.

If you really hit performance bottlenecks, investigate and optimize them *after* you noticed them. And I bet a factor 4 in a list manipulation will be the least of your problems, then.

**Edit:**
Someone mentioned that the lookup cost of "tuple" could cause the slowdown, but this is not the case:

```
In : f5 = lambda: tuple([x + 1 for x in a])

In : timeit.timeit(f5)
Out: 0.7900090217590332
```

So I guess it really is the generator expressions overhead which slows things down.

Comment: I would be willing to bet that the difference in time is not in the generator expression. I think it's more likely in the global namespace lookup of the names 'list' and 'tuple'. [] is built in syntax and doesn't require a lookup.

Answer (score 3):

The [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module can give you some idea of how the code executes internally...

`dis.dis(lambda a: [x + 1 for x in a])` yields...

```
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                16 (to 26)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
             13 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             16 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             19 BINARY_ADD
             20 LIST_APPEND              2
             23 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   26 RETURN_VALUE
```

...and `dis.dis(lambda a: tuple(x + 1 for x in a))` yields...

```
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (tuple)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x7f62e9eda930, file "<stdin>", line 1>)
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             12 GET_ITER
             13 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

...but you may not be able to infer much from that. If you want to know which is faster, check out the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, the efficiency between tuple and list really doesn't matter much.It you really care about it, you can use `timeit` to have a test.

The most important difference between tuple and list is that tuple is immutable and list is multable.
It means that you can change list's value but can't do it with tuple. You can hash tuple but can't do it to with list.
For example

```
k_tuple = ('a', 'b')
k_list = ['a', 'b']
d = {}
d[k_tuple] = 'c' # It is ok
d[k_list] = 'c' #It raise exception.
```

What's more, when list is as function's argument, it is assigned by reference. When tuple is as function's argument, it is assigned by value.